# I dont understand why I am getting error: 'else' without 'if' else

Tags: java, if-statement

I am not sure why I am getting the 'else without an if' error. My format is correct according to the book.

```
          if(donationType>2)
          {
             if(donationType == CLOTHING_CODE)
             {
                volunteer = CLOTHING_PRICER;
                message = "a clothing donation";
             }
             else
             {
                volunteer = OTHER_PRICER;
                message = "a non-clothing donation";
         }
         else
             message = "This is an invalid donation type";
             message = "The volunteer who will price this item is invalid";
         }
```

Comment: In Eclipse, if you double click right beside your curly brace it highlights the block of code covered by the brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a curly brace after the else

```
 if(donationType>2)
     {
         if(donationType == CLOTHING_CODE)
         {
            volunteer = CLOTHING_PRICER;
            message = "a clothing donation";
         }
         else
         {
            volunteer = OTHER_PRICER;
            message = "a non-clothing donation";
         }
    } 
     else
    {
         message = "This is an invalid donation type";
         message = "The volunteer who will price this item is invalid";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems :

**Problem 1 :**

You forgot to close the else part

```
 else
             {
                volunteer = OTHER_PRICER;
                message = "a non-clothing donation";
```

**Problem 2 :**

You forgot to open else branch, where as you are closing it correctly

```
 else
             message = "This is an invalid donation type";
             message = "The volunteer who will price this item is invalid";
         }
```

After corrections, Your code should be

```
 if(donationType>2)
          {
             if(donationType == CLOTHING_CODE)
             {
                volunteer = CLOTHING_PRICER;
                message = "a clothing donation";
             }
             else
             {
                volunteer = OTHER_PRICER;
                message = "a non-clothing donation";
              } // I added this 
         }
         else { // I added this
             message = "This is an invalid donation type";
             message = "The volunteer who will price this item is invalid";
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the first `else`'s closing brace `}`, so that the `}` you intended to end the first `if` actually ends the `else`, so you have 2 `else`s in a row, hence the error.

Supply the missing end brace `}` (and a beginning brace `{` for the last `else`).

Answer (score 0):

Every block of code always needs to be opened and closed properly.

```
else
         {
            volunteer = OTHER_PRICER;
            message = "a non-clothing donation";
/*YOU'RE MISSING AN ENDING BRACE HERE*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}`:

```
         else
         {
            volunteer = OTHER_PRICER;
            message = "a non-clothing donation";
         }
      // ^ was missing
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this from W3School, you are missing a bracket

```
if (condition1) {
    block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
} else if (condition2) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
} else {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
}
```